# Why don't compilers generate microinstructions rather than assembly code?

Tags: optimization, architecture, compiler-construction, assembly, low-level

I would like to know why, in the real world, compilers produce **Assembly code**, rather than **microinstructions**.

If **you're already bound to one architecture**, why not go one step further and free the processor from having to turn **assembly-code into microinstructions** at Runtime?

I think perhaps there's a **implementation bottleneck** somewhere but I haven't found anything on Google.

**EDIT** by microinstructions I mean: if you assembly instruction is ADD(R1,R2), the microinstructions would be. Load R1 to the ALU, load R2 to the ALU, execute the operation, load the results back onto R1. Another way to see this is to equate one microinstruction to one clock-cycle.

I was under the impression that microinstruction was the **'official'** name. Apparently there's some mileage variation here.

FA

Comment: Define what you mean by micro-instruction. The binary? Or the decoded micro-ops within the processor?

Comment: the micro operations.. I call them microinstructions.

Comment: Whats with the down-vote and close vote? This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: You mean the decoded micro-ops in the processor? (Just double-checking.) If so, the answer is it's not possible because the decoded micro-ops will vary even within the same ISA and processor line.

Comment: Every processor has different op-codes or instruction set that they understand. Assembly is needed to bridge the gap, its like having the JVM framework to run your java app on different OS. I cant explain this well enough to give an answer, so a comment will have to do.

Comment: I think the question is RISC vs. CISC again.

Comment: the compilers produce the machine code that the processor is able to execute.  If there were a processor that could execute microcode directly AND users had access to it then you might see something like that.  Not all processors are microcoded so you are already generating and executing the lowest level machine code.  Except perhaps for the transmeta experiment the low level code is likely not what you are expecting and not something can write apps in.

Comment: microcoded processors are designed specifically to convert one instruction set into state machine controls, etc for manipulating the rest of the processor.  Again except perhaps for transmeta and perhaps  some others they are specifically not designed to allow microcode to be run directly.

Comment: I dont think this is a RISC vs CISC thing again I think this is a "why cant I see or get at the microcode" thing again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compilers don't produce micro-instructions because processors don't execute micro-instructions.  They are an implementation detail of the chip, not something exposed outside the chip.  There's no way to provide micro-instructions to a chip.

Answer (score 8):

Because an x86 CPU doesn't execute micro operations, it executes opcodes. You can not create a binary image that contains micro operations since there is no way to encode them in a way that the CPU understands.

What you are suggesting is basically a new RISC-style instruction set for x86 CPUs. The reason that isn't happening is because it would break compatibility with the vast amount of applications and operating systems written for the x86 instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite easy.

(Some) compilers do indeed generate code sequences like load r1, load r2, add r2 to r1. But this are precisely the machine code instructions (that you call microcode). These instructions are the one and only interface between the outer world and the innards of a processor.

(Other compilers generate just C and let a C backend like gcc care about the dirty details.)